# crontab time for execution not using system 'date'

Tags: cron

My server was originally Eastern Time. But I used tzselect to change the timezone. Now typing date into the command line prints out the new timezone. But crontab still uses the old timezone to execute commands. How can I get crontab to use the new timezone? Is there something else that crontab uses for getting time/dates?

Comment: What happen if you just restart cron? I know that is ridiculous but... it is necessary for cron to get the new environment !

Comment: Or if cron is calling a script, set the TZ variable at the beginning of the script.

Comment: I restarted cron using `sudo service cron restart` but still same thing. Also no I am calling a python script from my crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. `tzselect` doesn't work. To change system wide time use: `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

Comment: FYI - It is a best practice (especially in large enterprises with multi-national offices) to have all systems, routers, switches, etc log using UTC. Users set their timezones locally. Definitely helps when troubleshooting network related issues and forensics of hacks, intrusions, and other anomalies.